# For Loop Over Files to Perform ncdump?

Tags: bash, shell, netcdf

Can't seem to find a solid similar question. In basic terms, I'm just trying to perform an action to multiple files but I struggle with for loops. I want to ncdump multiple files at once and store the output in separate files. This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

date='20160503'

dump1Dir=/server1/applications/VAL/gran_files

cd $dump1Dir
filelist=`ls *s$date*`

for i in $filelist do
ncdump $filelist > dumpfile[i]
done
```

Comment: It's not at all clear from what you wrote what you actually want to do. You might try to explain using a concise explanation, such as "For each file whose name matches the pattern ..., I want to use ncdump to create a human-readable file called ..." An example wouldn't hurt, either.

Comment: I want to execute an "ncdump" command on several hundred files and store the output in separate text files, so output1.txt, output2.txt, and so on. I understand what ncdump does, I'm trying to execute it over hundreds of files without having to manually ncdump every single file.

Comment: I got that you want a loop. But I don't know what you want to name the output files or where you want them to be written, since `dumpfile[i]` is meaningless. So my answer makes several assumptions.

Comment: I wanted to name the output files just something generic, like "dumpfile1", "dumpfile2", etc, so that I would know the file was the output result of an ncdump. The [i] was supposed to be an interation, like 1,2,3,4,5,etc. I get very confused with for loops and syntax, hope this clarifies. You answered the question with a result that works for me, regardless of output file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that what you want is something like:

```
for file in *s$date*.nc; do ncdump "$file" > "${file%.nc}.cdf"; done
```

but that includes a bunch of assumptions.

What it will do is:

- Find all files whose name ends with the extension `.nc`, and includes an `s` followed by the value of the variable `$date`
- For each such file, use `ncdump` to create a file with the same name, changing the extension from `nc` to `cdf`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well (assuming source file has .nc extension, and output is using .cdf)

```
cd $dump1Dir
ls -1 *s$date*.nc | while read file; do ncdump "$file" > "${file%.nc}.cdf"; done
```